# Can SES SMTP User Credentials be reused for multiple EC2 instances, or does it get tied to one instance after it has been used?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, smtp, sendmail, amazon-ses

I have been trying to send emails using sendmail configured with AWS's SES. I've had some trouble with one instance. Then after some trouble shooting and fixing things around, I had an smtp credentials generated from AWS IAM. I put that in my /etc/mail/authinfo and followed the necessary steps. Once I did this, I was able to send mail through SES.

I tried using the same smtp credentials on another instance using AWS SES and Sendmail linking (literally followed the same procedure). However, I keep on this error in /var/mail/my_user_name

```
530 Authentication required
554 5.0.0 Service unavailable
```

So, the question is, can the SES smtp user credentials be reused for multiple instances? In other words, does it get tied to an IP/Instance once its been used?

I am on connecting via an EC2 ubuntu instance and have all the required sudo privileges.

Comment: SES SMTP user credentials are not tied to a specific EC2 instance.

Comment: yes, but once you use it with one instance, does it mean you cant use it elsewhere?

Comment: Edited question to reflect the question better.

Comment: maybe a potential security group or networking/firewall/port access issue

Comment: no that is not the case here since the two instances I tried using the same smtp credentials are under the same security group/firewall

Comment: If using it with one instance meant you couldn't use it elsewhere, then that would mean the credentials were "tied" to the first instance. Credentials aren't tied/locked/restricted to a specific instance, and they don't become tied/locked/restricted to a specific instance once they are used there.